# How to perform a batch of exclusive update or insert operations with a List of items in Quarkus Panache?

Tags: mysql, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I'm working on a Quarkus project using Panache for data persistence. I know that `PanacheRepositoryBase` already has `persist(Iterable<Entity> entities)` function and that accepts a collection of items to persist. However as far as I know its more of an `upsert` function that will either insert/update.

My questions are:

1. Is there a function that exclusively accepts inserting multiple data? so if I use `insert` when the `pk` already exists, it will get rejected.
2. Is there a function that exclusively accepts updating multiple data? I'm aware of `update(..)` function, but they did not seem to accept a Collection/Iterable for parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, that doesn’t exist. You have to build that yourself.

And I would recommend you doing that by injecting a StatelessSession (and enabling batching) rather than using Panache.